Kotlin ktor OAuth - How to modify access token url?
EDIT : I was referring to kotlin server oauth docs. But kotlin has a client side doc for OAuth as well. I will try this out and update here.
I am trying to connect to airtable using OAuth from Kotlin ktor. The authorization is getting completed successfully, but I have some issues during redirection and during access token requests.
Here's how my code looks like
OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
                    name = "airtable",
                    authorizeUrl = "https://airtable.com/oauth2/v1/authorize",
                    accessTokenUrl = "https://airtable.com/oauth2/v1/token",
                    requestMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
                    clientId = clientId,
                    clientSecret = clientSecret,
                    defaultScopes = listOf("data.records:read"),
                    extraAuthParameters = listOf(
                        "code_challenge" to codeChallenge,
                        "code_challenge_method" to "S256"
                    ),
                    extraTokenParameters = listOf(),
                    accessTokenInterceptor = {
                        val credentials = "$clientId:$clientSecret".toUrlEncoded()
                        val authorizationHeader = "Basic $credentials"
                        val contentTypeHeader = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

                        this.headers.set("Authorization", authorizationHeader)
                        this.headers.set("Content-Type", contentTypeHeader)

                        val params = Parameters.build {
                            append("code", "$somecode")
                            append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/redirect")
                            append("grant_type", "authorization_code")
                            append("code_verifier", codeVerifier)
                        }
                        this.setBody(FormDataContent(params))
                    },
                    onStateCreated = { call, state ->
                        //saves new state with redirect url value
                        call.request.queryParameters["redirectUrl"]?.let {
                            redirects[state] = airtableOAuthParams
                        }
                    }
                )

And this is how my route looks right now
routing {
        authenticate("airtable-oauth") {
            get("/login") {
            }
            get("/redirect") {
                call.respondText("Login successful", status = HttpStatusCode.OK)
            }
        }
    }

So after login, I get redirected to Airtable's authorization page. If I click on Grant access in Airtable, it tries to redirect to "/redirect" url. But ktor first tries to call access token url, I think because "/redirect" route is inside authenticate.
According to airtable docs to hit access token endpoint, we must pass the grant code we got from authorization endpoint, as a body parameter. When ktor hits the end point it doesn't pass the code as a body param. So I used the accessTokenInterceptor param in OAuth2ServerSettings. But don't know how I can access the grant code there. If I keep redirect endpoint outside of authenticate then I'm getting the grant code as a query parameter of the url. Can someone guide me on how to store this code and access it inside accessTokenInterceptor? Should I use Sessions to achieve that?

As I can see, the Ktor OAuth implementation fetches the code and sends it within the body of the token creation request. Can you remove the code of the accessTokenInterceptor, go through the OAuth flow, and share the error from the airtable?

I have completely removed accessTokenInterceptor and I'm getting invalid_client error. But my client credentials are correct.
These are the logs
2024-06-05 18:27:25.617 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE io.ktor.auth.oauth - OAuth2 request access token failed io.ktor.server.auth.OAuth2Exception$UnknownException: Invalid client credentials. (error code = invalid_client)

https://airtable.com/developers/web/api/oauth-reference#token-creation-request
In here it is mentioned that, for token url couple of headers needs to be present. Does ktor sends this by default? Do I need to override accessTokenInterceptor for it?

If I just add headers in accessTokenInterceptor then I'm getting this error from Airtable
io.ktor.server.auth.OAuth2Exception$UnknownException: Token requests must include "code_verifier" (error code = invalid_request)

@AlekseiTirman I have added some logs inside accessTokenInterceptor and in body I'm not seeing any grant code being sent in it. Only client id is there in body.

I was able to fix this OAuth problem. I made multiple mistakes which took time to find out and get fixed. Here are the fixes.

Moving crypto strings out of provider lookup. Airtable requires us to generate some crypto strings and use it during both authorization and token api hits. Looks like provider lookup is called for authorization and token api separately. So I generated different random strings for these two. Moving this out of provider lookup fixed this issue.
Adding access_type as "offline". Turns out this is required to generate new tokens.
This is Airtable specific. They require code_verifier in token url, that I added in extraTokenParameters.

Following is the full working code.
fun Application.configureRouting() {
    install(Authentication) {
        val codeVerifier = cryptographicString(43)
        val encryptedVerifier = codeVerifier.sha256Encrypt()
        val codeChallenge =
            Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedVerifier)
                .replace("=", "").replace("+", "-").replace("/", "_")
        val clientId = "client-id"
        val clientSecret = "client-secret"

        oauth("my-oauth") {
            client = applicationHttpClient
            // Configure oauth authentication
            urlProvider = { "http://localhost:8080/redirect" }
            providerLookup = {

                OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
                    name = "airtable",
                    authorizeUrl = "https://airtable.com/oauth2/v1/authorize",
                    accessTokenUrl = "https://airtable.com/oauth2/v1/token",
                    requestMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
                    clientId = clientId,
                    clientSecret = clientSecret,
                    defaultScopes = listOf(
                        "data.records:read",
                        "data.records:write",
                        "schema.bases:read",
                        "user.email:read"
                    ),
                    extraAuthParameters = listOf(
                        "code_challenge" to codeChallenge,
                        "code_challenge_method" to "S256",
                        "access_type" to "offline"
                    ),
                    accessTokenRequiresBasicAuth = true,
                    extraTokenParameters = listOf(
                        "code_verifier" to codeVerifier
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }


    routing {
        authenticate("my-oauth") {
            get("/login") {
            }
            get("/redirect") {
                call.respondText("Welcome User", status = HttpStatusCode.OK)
            }
        }
        get("/home") {
            call.respondText("Hello World!")
        }
        get("/") {
            call.respondHtml {
                body {
                    p {
                        a("/login") { +"Login with Airtable" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun cryptographicString(length: Int): String {
    val allowedChars = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9') + "." + "-"
    return (1..length).map { allowedChars.random() }.joinToString("")
}

fun String.sha256Encrypt(): ByteArray {
    return Hashing.sha256().hashString(this, Charsets.UTF_8).asBytes()
}


Thanks @Aleksei Tirman for your suggestion. I removed the accessTokenInterceptor as well.

The one problem I see is that the codeVerifier and the codeChallange are the same for every client, which can lead to the security issues.

Noted. I'll keep it with reference to state inside provider lookup.
